# How to Format React Form Submission Before API Gets Payload

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, payload, react-functional-component

I am trying to submit a form that takes form field inputs into a React hook state object. However, the payload object is accessed by other components in the application that expect the payload object to be a certain format.

```
const [formInput, setFormInput] = useState();

const onChange = event => {
 event.target.name = event.target.value;
}

return (
<form onSubmit="props.onSubmit">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input value="formInput.first-name" name="first-name" onChange={onChange}></input>
  <input value="formInput.person-dept" name="person-dept" onChange={onChange}></input>
  <button type="submit">Add a cadet</button>
</form>
)
```

So, the formInput object has two properties. But they need to be nested, like this:

```
//acceptable payload:
{cadet: [
  first-name: '',
  dept: ''
 ]
}
```

I have tried calling a function for wrapping them using a new state object, but it gives me an undefined error for the schema property:

```
const schema = () => {
  cadet: [
    first-name: '',
    dept: ''
 ]
}

const [formattedInput, setFormattedInput] = useState(schema);

const updateInput = () => {
  setFormattedInput(
    cadet: {
     {first-name: {formInput.first-name} || null},
     {dept: {formInput.person-dept} || null}
    }
  )
}

updateInput();

api.post('~/person/cadet', updateInput);
```

In the above example, the properties from schema are undefined, cadet and first-name.
Also, in order to set the setFormattedInput object before calling the API I need to instantiate the function that has it, but because of React rules, calling updateInput(); runs when the component is rendered and is undefined (sort of like needing a componentDidUpdate() for a functional component).

This should be very common- we all need to reformat our form state objects before they reach the API unless you are building an application from scratch. Does anybody know how?

To give some context, the NPM package mapper does what is needed, but it simply doesn't work (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapper).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a custom wrapper and fixing minor syntax issues along the way. In the payload,

```
api.post('~/person/cadet', formInput);
```

I added

```
const formattedObj = formatted(formInput);
api.post('~/person/cadet', formattedObj);
console.log(formattedObj);
```

Then in the same file I defined formatted like this:

```
const formatted = (formInput) => {

  const payload = {cadet: [
    first-name: formInput.first-name,
    dept: formInput.person-dept
 ]}
return payload;
}
```

Therefore, formatted() gets passed in the state object and payload is behaving sort of like a block variable and doesn't need to be called for it to be the data being returned by formatted().

Just a minor step of wrapping the object passed to the URL path and some syntax in formatted() and the basic workflow was correct.

I wanted to share because it took several powerful coworker minds to make this work and it should be taught with React hooks everywhere to lower the barriers to entry.

Thanks for reading and I hope this works for you, too!

P.S.- If the object isn't being saved, it's due to other syntax issues in what you are passing into the object from the form fields. Also, minor syntax tweaks will get this solution to work if something is a tiny bit off.